# Toggle button text upon click

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a DIV (`#newmsg`) that I hide using jQuery with a button:

```
<input type="button" id="hideshow" value="New Post">
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#newmsg').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

I want to toggle the value of the input button from `New Post` to `Cancel` whenever someone clicks on the button. How do I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide `.toggle(showOrHide)` means `true` or `false`, not `"show"` or `"hide"` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the value of the button use `.val()`
`.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()`
try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#hideshow', function(event) {        
         if(jQuery(this).val() == 'New Post'){
             jQuery(this).val("Cancel");
         }
         else{
             jQuery(this).val("New Post");
         }
         jQuery('#newmsg').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my question. I want to change the button text whenever someone clicks on it from "New Post" to "Cancel". So toggle back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         if(jQuery(this).val() == 'New Post'){
             jQuery(this).val("Cancel");
         }
         else{
             jQuery(this).val("New Post");
         }
         jQuery('#newmsg').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have in my file a `toggleText()` function that i've adjusted for you (you change the value). just use this code:

```
//Copyright Karl-André Gagnon
jQuery.prototype.toggleText = function(t1, t2){
    var obj = {};
    obj[t1] = t2;
    obj[t2] = t1;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).val(obj[$(this).val()])
    })
}


jQuery(document).on('click', '#hideshow', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleText('New Post', 'Cancel');
    jQuery('#newmsg').toggle('show');
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tt36q/8/